# Does the following sentence need a comma before the word "and"?

Tags: punctuation

> "It’s like in this time, in this age, people aren’t stressing the
>   importance of grammar usage enough and it enrages me to no end."

With the addition of a comma in front of "and", is the sentence below grammatically correct?

> "It’s like in this time, in this age, people aren’t stressing the
>   importance of grammar usage **enough, and** it enrages me to no end."

Comment: Its like, not particularly upscale usage to start with "it's like".  It's, you know, like, um, Valspeak. Also "enrages me to no end" means enrages but with no purpose.  "enrages me no end" means enrages extremely.  So it seems to me that the writer of that rant has no legs to stand on his high horse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style, and you should consult your style manual, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which dictates that a comma should separate conjoined independent clauses "unless they are short and closely related."  You have two independent clauses -- "people aren't" and "it enrages."

Here's an example in which a comma is unnecessary:

> I asked and he answered.

Short and closely related.  Do your clauses qualify?  It's a judgment call, but I would recommend leaving the comma to avoid what Steven Pinker, the author of *The Sense of Style*,  calls "garden paths," constructs that mislead your reader into initially parsing your sentence in a way that you ultimately don't follow.  If you leave out the comma, your reader may expect a *compound predicate* instead of a new clause.  That is, they will read

> It’s like in this time, in this age, people *aren’t stressing* the
>   importance of grammar usage enough **and**

and expect something like this to follow:

> **and** *are* in fact, *stressing* an anything-goes approach to writing.

As a kindness to your readers, let a comma signal "new clause ahead."

Answer (score 0):

No - it works either with or without the comma.

With the comma provides more emphasis; without the comma gives the sentence more flow.

Comment: That's one opinion. :)